# MP4 does not play from Azure Blob on Android

Tags: android, html, video, azure-blob-storage, video.js

I have the following video HTML:

```
<video id="player_a" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" title="Home video" width="640" poster="~/Assets/img/video_poster_full.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="https://#####.blob.core.windows.net/video/homepage-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://#####.blob.core.windows.net/video/homepage-video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="https://#####.blob.core.windows.net/video/homepage-video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
        <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
</video>
```

On Android, this video does not play from the webpage. But as soon as I change my video host from the Azure Blob to my own private server (http://myserver.net/images/homepage-video.mp4), it streams fine.

I notice that if I just go directly to the URL of the .mp4, it does not load from Blob (but *does* from my private server). I also notice that the .webm does load okay from Blob but for some reason, my video is not falling back to that format.

Are there any settings I need to change in Azure Blob to allow .mp4 to be streamed differently? Or what am I doing wrong that is not causing the video to fall back to .webm?

Answer (score 0):

The permissions on your blob will need to be public to make sure that you can access the content without a key. You can check this in the properties of the container.

In the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-manage-access-to-resources/#grant-anonymous-users-permissions-to-containers-and-blobs) you can find an excellent post on how to set these permissions up.